# Application of two dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

When I run this code I am having a blank output on my command prompt. So please help me with my code.

```
class MulTable
{
  final static int ROWS = 0;
  final static int COLUMNS = 40;
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
     int myproduct[][] = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];
     int rows, column;
     System.out.println("MULTIPLICATION TABLE");
     System.out.println(" ");
     int i,j;
     for (i=10; i<ROWS; i++)
     {
        for(j=10; j<COLUMNS ;j++)
        {
           myproduct[i][j] =i*j;
           System.out.print(" "+myproduct[i][j]);
           
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
     }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You haven't told us any details about what's supposed to be happening, but regardless the loop will never be entered if `ROWS = 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works

```
public class MulTable
{
 final static int ROWS = 20;
 final static int COLUMNS = 40;
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      int myproduct[][] = new int[ROWS][COLUMNS];
      System.out.println("MULTIPLICATION TABLE");
      System.out.println(" ");
      int i,j;
      for (i=10; i<ROWS; i++)
      {
         for(j=10; j<COLUMNS ;j++)
         {
            myproduct[i][j] =i*j;
            System.out.print(" "+myproduct[i][j]);
       
         }
    System.out.println(" ");
   }
  }
}
```

The problem was that you initialized ROW with 0 at line no 5

```
final static int ROWS = 0;
```

and at line no 13

```
for (i=10; i<ROWS; i++)
```

you are checking that if i < ROWS , here i is initialized with 10 and ROWS is 0, so condition i<ROWS becomes false and for loop is not entered

I changed value of ROWS to 20 and now its working.
Enter value for ROWS anything greater than 10 and it will work